# Unknown exception in custom JButton, in java (swing)

Tags: java, swing, exception, custom-controls

I have tried to create a custom JButton. I tried to paint its caption via the paintComponent method but i did not like the font rendering of this method. So I added a JLabel to my button which worked fine in first place but after removing the parts for the paintString stuff the compiler throws errors i do not know how to fix/solve. Also what can I improve?

**The JButtons code:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

class myImageButton extends JButton implements MouseListener {

  private Color fontColor = new Color(0x222);

  private Image btn = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("btn.png");
  private Image btnHvr = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("btnhvr.png");
  private Image btnDwn = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("btndwn.png");
  private Image fallback = btn;
  private Image currentImage = btn;

  private JFrame parent;
  private JLabel label;

  private boolean mouseDown = false;
  private int captionWidth;
  private int captionHeight;
  private Font font = new Font("Open Sans", Font.PLAIN, 12);
  private FontMetrics fm = new FontMetrics(font) { };

  myImageButton(String text, JFrame parent) {
    parent = parent;
    Rectangle2D bounds = fm.getStringBounds(text, null);
    captionWidth = (int) bounds.getWidth();
    captionHeight = (int) bounds.getHeight();
    addMouseListener(this);
    setBounds(0,0,79,28);
    setFont(font);
    label = new JLabel(text);
    this.add(label);
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(parent.getBackground());
    g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
    g.drawImage(currentImage,0,0,parent);
    //g.setColor(fontColor);
    //g.drawString(caption, getWidth() / 2 - captionWidth / 2, getHeight() / 2 + captionHeight / 3);
  }

  public void paintBorder(Graphics g) {
  }  

  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    //mouse down
    currentImage = btnDwn;
    mouseDown = true;
    repaint();
  }

  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    //mouse up
    currentImage = btnHvr;
    mouseDown = false;
    repaint();
  }

  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    //hover on
    if (mouseDown) {
      currentImage = btnDwn;
    } else {
      currentImage = btnHvr;
    }
    repaint();
  }

  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    //hover off
    if (mouseDown) {
      currentImage = btnDwn;
    } else {
      currentImage = btn;
    }
    repaint();
  }

  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    //click
    //should be managed by parent UI class
  }  

}
```

**The JFrames code:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Launch {
  public static void main (String[]args) {
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    myImageButton cp = new myImageButton("Exit", jf);
    jf.setLayout(null);
    jf.setSize(640,480);
    jf.setResizable(false);

    jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.add(cp);
    cp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 
        myImageButton_ActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });
    cp.setLocation(50,50);
    jf.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void myImageButton_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    System.out.println("Click");
  }
}
```

**The full exception stackTrace:**

```
Starte C:\Users\Selim\Desktop\Launch.java

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at myImageButton.paintComponent(myImageButton.java:38)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at myImageButton.paintComponent(myImageButton.java:38)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at myImageButton.paintComponent(myImageButton.java:38)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at myImageButton.paintComponent(myImageButton.java:38)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at myImageButton.paintComponent(myImageButton.java:38)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at myImageButton.paintComponent(myImageButton.java:38)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at myImageButton.paintComponent(myImageButton.java:38)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks in advance!

Selim

Comment: Don't post links to code please, copy the relevant parts to your question.

Comment: Nice nested scroll bars :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here in the constructor of `myImageButton`:

```
parent = parent;
```

The local parent `JFrame` reference is assigned to itself. Subsequently in `paintComponent`, the class member variable `parent` is `null` producing an `NPE`. You want

```
this.parent = parent;
```

> Also what can I improve?

- Don't use `null` layout, always use a [layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)
- The `JButton` component already offers the functionality provided by the custom button by using the following methods: [setBorder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBorder%28javax.swing.border.Border%29), [setPressedIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setPressedIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29), [setRollOverIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setRolloverIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29)
- Follow Java naming conventions. Classes start with an *uppercase* letter such as   `MyImageButton`

Comment: Ah thank you so much I must have removed that part accidentally when cleaning up the needless attributes for the drawString.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to center the text on top of the button icon. The API handles this:

```
button.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
button.setVerticalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
```

The API also handles different icons. Check the API for any method with "Icon" in the method name.

Comment: hey unfortunately that does not work but ive found a solution that works:
setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
this.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
this.add(label);  <br/>
this.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

Comment: @Selim, I think you miss the point. There is no need to create a custom JButton. The button will position the text over the icon using the above code.

Comment: If you mean calling the setText(string s) method of super class: the text will not get displayed doing it that way - maybe because of the images

Comment: @Selim, I mean there is no need to create a class called "MyImageButton". There is no need to do custom painting. There is no need to write your own MouseListener.

Comment: of course there is (for me at least) i paint my buttons in theGIMP and using this code i can use then as jbuttons in my apps. the normal jbutton doesnt offer this functionality. i dont want to change look and feel only but use my own drawn buttons there. not only change the icon on the button but the whole button itself. i hope you know what i am trying to say.